# Put text from a .txt file into <p> tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, cordova

I have an app I'm developing using `PhoneGap`, `HTML` and `JavaScript` and so far I have the app downloading a file and reading it to the `console.log`. I now want to read it into specified `<p>` tags but when I try a technique I know to work when reading a file from the `LocalFileSystem` it doesn't work. Here's the code;

```
    function downloadfile() {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/readme.txt");

        fileTransfer.download(
                uri,
                '/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AF96D141-0CE5-4D60-9FA8-8A8F9A999C81/Documents/readme.txt',
                function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                }
        );
    }

    function readDownloadedFile() {
        myFileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotDownloadFileEntry, fail);
            var myDownload = document.getElementById("mytext");
            myDownload.innerText = text;
    }

    function gotDownloadFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        console.log(fileEntry);
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }
```

The function `readDownloadFile()` is supposed to read the text in the .txt file `readme.txt` into the `<p>` tags with the id `mytext`.  However, when I try and run it nothing happens. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about PhoneGap but so far I can't see any initial function call...?

Comment: sorry - `<button onclick = 'readDownloadedFile();'>read Downloaded</button>` - i put it in html away from the function so i forgot to put it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you, to use a simple ajax call to

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/readme.txt

and pass it into your p tag.

like

```
$('#mytext').load('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/readme.txt', function(){
   alert("i am done")
});
```

check http://api.jquery.com/load/

This needs to be invoked by a click event or something. (In your example it's not invoked)

Comment: i invoked it in a button in HTML - sorry i forgot to put it in - `<button onclick = 'readDownloadedFile();'>read Downloaded</button>`